# Can a compiler compile code without an extention?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

This is a random question that came to me, obviously I wouldn't want to do it because it is bad practice, but is it possible to compile and run code from a file without an extension?  Does this work with c,c++, java, python, any languages?  If it does, than is the extension more of a stylist property or does it have a purpose for something else?

Comment: File extensions don't mean anything.  I can name an HTML file with a .jpg ending.  It's just data on a disk: how software interprets the data is what's important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension doesn't mean anything. Just a way to help you keep track of what file is what. (also helps stuff like a GUI explorer open the file in the right program).

(Java might care becuase the language spec says a source files end in .java, but there may be a way to hack it).

Comment: Of course it's harder for a compiler frontend serving multiple languages. But yes, the file extension is nowhere as important as many people think.

Answer (score 4):

This depends more on the used compiler than on the language. E.g. gcc/g++ has a commandline option `-x <language>` that allows to override the detection based on the file extension. One use-case is using `-` (i.e. stdin) as input.

Comment: If you don't even need a file, how can you need an extension? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is really compiler dependent.  For example, I would imagine that there are C/C++ compiler dispatchers that make some assumptions based on the file ending in .c or .cpp but there may also be command line options to explicitly specify how a file should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers can accept multiple types of files in a build, and use the extension of a file to determine what to do with it.  For example, one might be able to say:

```
acmecompile foo.c bar.c fred.cpp wow.asm lib1.lib compilething.obj -o result.exe
```

It would use the extensions of the various files to determine that the first two should be fed through the C compiler, the next through a C++ compiler, and the next through an assembler.  The last two should be fed directly to the linker.

Often, there will be some means of telling a compiler that a particular file should be handled a particular way regardless of its extension; for example, it may sometimes be desirable to some files in a multi-targeted application compile as C for some targets and C++ for others (on one of my projects, the primary target is built in C and uses hardware I/O registers; while another target, built with C++, replaces those registers with properties).